# Why does Ruby on Rails run slowly on VMWare

Tags: centos5, ruby-on-rails, vmware-esx, central-processing-unit

We are experiencing slow performance of our Ruby on Rails application on a hosted server.

Neither us nor our hosting provider have been able to accurately diagnose the reason for this.

Indicators of slow performance are the time to process web requests or restart the application when compared to our staging system, despite better hardware.  For example starting a rails console takes >1 minute on this environment compared to <20seconds on staging.

We use:-

- VMWare
- Cent OS 5.8
- Phusion Passenger.
- Ruby 1.9.2

Our hosting provider is suggesting migrating the VM from AMD to Intel hardware, as they believe some applications work better on Intel. I have not been able to find any documentation explaining this.

I have looked at some other obvious causes such as...

- ensuring all latest patches are applied
- no unexpected processes running
- VMWare issue such as  [Linux 2.6 kernel-based virtual machines experience slow disk I/O performance](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2011861)

...however I have not been able to identify anything obviously wrong.

Any advise on steps to diagnose or areas to check would be very much appreciated.

**Further Information**
1. Underlying host hardware.  I dont have full details, but CPUs are AMD Opteron 6172 CPU. 2. We use RVM and installed ruby with this command:
rvm install 1.9.2
3. We use same setup in staging - Passenger+Apache. the time to restart is significantly shorter in staging.

Comment: Do you have any information about the underlying host hardware?

Comment: Is it the same exact Ruby build in both the hosted environment and your reference system? (Is Ruby built with `--enable-pthread` or `--disable-pthread`?)

Comment: It might depend from many factors.
RoR performances in production is a tricky topic.

Do you use Passenger also in staging (Standalone, Apache or NginX)? It's normal that restarting it, it must respawn processes and takes long.

Is the data volume in production significantly greater than staging?

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much for these suggestions.  1. Underlying host hardware.  I dont have full details, but CPUs are AMD Opteron 6172 CPU . 2. We use RVM and have not explictly set pthread option. I did a bit of research, and it sounds like this is not an issue in ruby 1.9 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707061/installing-ruby-without-pthreads-using-rvm). 3. Yes, we use same setup in staging - Passenger+Apache. the time to restart is significantly shorter in staging.